# how to serve my static files in condition below

Tags: node.js, express, backend

[image]

```
router.use(express.static('public'));

router.get('/edit-page/:slug',function(req, res){

    Page.findOne({slug: req.params.slug}, function(err, page) {
        if(err)
            return console.log(err);

        res.render('admin/edit_page', {
            title: page.title,
            slug: page.slug,
            content : page.content,
            id: page._id
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it -

**1. Read the HTML file and send it to the client.**

```
    app.get('/', (req, res) => {
      fs.readFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html', 'utf8', (err, text) => {
        res.send(text);
      });
   });
```

**2. You can have a jade or EJS template engine. include a plain HTML page:**

in views/index.jade

```
include plain.html
in views/plain.html
```

...
and app.js can still just render jade:

```
res.render(index)
```

Note - set the engine type in your app.js file

```
app.set("view engine","jade")
```

Comment: i added my folder structure i want to serve those public folder static files